# Where are Windows' store printer drivers names located?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, printer, windows-store

I can install a printer driver with `pnputil` by using:

```
pnputil.exe /add-driver .\MYINF.inf /install /subdirs
```

I can enumerate them with

```
pnputil /enum-drivers /class "printer"
```

But when I have to add them to the list of printers drivers I have to use the name

```
Add-PrinterDriver -Name ???
```

Where is the driver name stored?

Answer (score 1):

The driver name is for example  "HP Universal Printing PS (v7.0.1)"
This name is located in the INF file for your printer.

A single INF may contain multiple driver names if the same driver or one included with the other included files is supported.

I wrote a vbs script to install printers and that is what I used which is what works.

Comment: thanks!, I no longer need it but maybe you can include the part of the script that takes the driver name, it may be useful